# Ubuntu packages not upgraded

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm getting this when running apt on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

```bash
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  base-files gnome-remote-desktop gnome-software gnome-software-common
  gnome-software-plugin-flatpak gnome-software-plugin-snap gstreamer1.0-gtk3
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
  language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
  libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 python3-distupgrade
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

Now, these are only Ubuntu packages, so this is surprising. I've run the usual fixes such as `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt -f install`, but I keep getting the same output

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you!